# Error Log levels Apache 2.4

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, centos7

Is there any way to temporally get more detailed log errors in Apache 2.4.6 on Centos 7 ,if so , what would it be the way to look into the actual level of logging and which one would it be the way to get detailed logging . As Apache suggest there is a " LogLevel info rewrite:trace5 " on http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html but what would it be the way to look at the actual level? I've concern about changing and couldn't know how to get back and have that "memory issue" as said in the website. Do I understand that correctly? would it be the case to change the log errorlevel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Setting Apache's logging verbosity

The detail of logging provided by Apache is controlled via the `Loglevel` directive. See the [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#loglevel) for details.

Set the value according to your needs, and run

```
service httpd restart
```

to apply.

There is no way to make Apache httpd change its verbosity while it's running, unfortunately.

Some modules (like mod_php, mod_log_forensics, mod_security) though have their own way of increasing their logs' detail level, please see the module's docs for those - some of those may allow increasing verbosity without restarting httpd (e.g. mod_php using php.ini for PHP errors).

With Apache httpd some of those (like mod_rewrite) directives were incorporated into the Loglevel directive and thus need httpd to be restarted.

## Inspecting Apache's settings

If you want to know which directive has which value in a running apache instance, have a look at [mod_info](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_info.html).

On RHEL, its output at http://host/server-info (you have to enable it first) looks like this:

```
In file: /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
 260: ServerAdmin root@localhost
 283: UseCanonicalName Off
 290: DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
 300: <Directory />
 301:   Options FollowSymLinks
 302:   AllowOverride None
    : </Directory>
 315: <Directory "/var/www/html">
 329:   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
 336:   AllowOverride None
    : </Directory>
 407: AccessFileName .htaccess
 433: DefaultType text/plain
 453: HostnameLookups Off
 481: ErrorLog logs/error_log
 *488: LogLevel warn*
 533: ServerSignature On
 550: <Directory "/var/www/icons">
 551:   Options Indexes MultiViews
 552:   AllowOverride None
    : </Directory>
 579: <Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
 580:   AllowOverride None
 581:   Options None
    : </Directory>
 756: AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
 850: <Directory "/var/www/error">
 851:   AllowOverride None
 852:   Options IncludesNoExec
    : </Directory>
```

Comment: well, this is embarrasing . That easy of course. Thanks @fuero

Answer (score 3):

Apache loglevels are:

```
emerg   Emergencies - system is unusable.   
alert   Action must be taken immediately.   
crit    Critical Conditions.    
error   Error conditions.   
warn    Warning conditions.  
notice  Normal but significant condition.   
info    Informational.  
debug   Debug-level messages    
trace1  Trace messages  
trace2  Trace messages  
trace3  Trace messages  
trace4  Trace messages  
trace5  Trace messages  
trace6  Trace messages  
trace7  Trace messages, dumping large amounts of data   
trace8  Trace messages, dumping large amounts of data
```

Use it in your httpd.conf or virtualhosts like: `LogLevel debug` When a particular level is specified, messages from all other levels of higher significance will be reported as well. E.g., when `LogLevel info` is specified, then messages with log levels of notice and warn will also be posted.